# Linking searches with correct controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have the following in my controller:

```
def index
    @games = Game.gamsearch(params[:gamsearch])
end

def consearch
    @games = Game.consearch(params[:consearch])
end

def gensearch
    @games = Game.gensearch(params[:gensearch]) 
end
```

And the following in my view:

```
<div id="sidehead"><h2><%= t('.search') %></h2></div>
<div id="searching" >
        <%= form_tag games_path, :controller => 'games', :action => 'gamsearch', :method => 'get' do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :gamsearch, params[:gamsearch] %>
        <%= submit_tag t('.searchb'), :game_name => nil %>
    <% end %>   
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"/>

<div id="sidehead"><h2><%= t('.search') %></h2></div>
<div id="searching" >
        <%= form_tag games_path, :controller => 'games', :action => 'gensearch', :method => 'get' do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :gensearch, params[:gensearch] %>
        <%= submit_tag t('.searchb'), :game_name => nil %>
    <% end %>   
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"/>

<div id="sidehead"><h2><%= t('.search') %></h2></div>
<div id="searching" >
        <%= form_tag games_path, :controller => 'games', :action => 'consearch', :method => 'get' do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :consearch, params[:consearch] %>
        <%= submit_tag t('.searchb'), :game_name => nil %>
    <% end %>   
</div>
```

Now the first search works fine and by looking at the log it connects with that in the index. But the second two searches do nothing and by looking at the log they are not connecting to their associated con and gensearch. Any ideas? Is it possible to specify which method in the controller to use?

```
resources :games do
   post 'email', :on => :member
   post 'gensearch', :on => :member
   post 'consearch', :on => :member
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form_tag games_path, :controller => 'games', :action => 'consearch', :method => 'get'
```

The first parameter to `form_tag`, `games_path`, is setting the URL options. The rest of your hash is being swallowed up by the `options` param.

I'm not sure what your routes look like, but you should be able to do this the verbose way.

```
form_tag( {:controller => 'games', :action => 'consearch'}, {:method => 'get'} )
```

Note that you are mapping your resources with `post` in your routes, but you're using `get` in your forms. That going to cause your path helpers to not work properly.

Comment: I changed my code to the following line 'code' <%= form_tag ( {:controller => 'games', :action => 'gamsearch'}, {:method => 'get'} ) do %> 'code' but that didn't work. It raised a lot of errors.

Comment: I added my routes to the bottom of the post

Comment: Posting the errors would help a lot. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: It's ok I have fixed it now, just had to put a if params.present? at the end